# WebSocket Server with Ratchet: Can two requests run at the same time?

Tags: websocket, ratchet

I have a general question about building a WebSocket server (in my case with Ratchet - http://socketo.me/). When two requests are sent to the server in the exact same moment, will the server execute them simultaneously or one after the other?

Example:
User 1 sends a message "abc" to the server. User 2 sends a message "xyz".
In the onMessage function, I write the message to a property of my class. Can I be sure, that while the rest of the script executes, the property remains the same, or could the second request overwrite the first before it finishes executing?